# echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields! "; does not appear after clicking register button

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

$submit = isset($_POST['submit']);

$fullname = strip_tags(isset($_POST['fullname']));
$username = strip_tags(isset($_POST['username']));

$password = strip_tags(isset($_POST['password']));
$repeatpassword = strip_tags(isset($_POST['repeatpassword']));
$date = date("Y-m-d");

if ($submit)
{
    if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
    {


    }
    else
        echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields! ";  
}

?>
```

**The PHP Code above is the edited code with isset function.**
Why is it that echo `"Please fill in <b>all</b> fields! ";` does not appear after clicking register button?. Any suggestion to run the program successfully?
Before inserting `isset()` function the code runs successfully. Anyone can explain?
Any Suggestions or any code structure?
I'm trying to create a login-registration system for the office.

Im a newbie in Php.
Included in the code is the full html used.

Thank you

**The PHP Code below is the original code that outputs an error:**

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 4

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: fullname in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: repeatpassword in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 10

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

$submit = $_POST['submit'];

$fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

  if ($submit)
    {
     //check for existence
  if ($fullname&&$username&&$password&&$repeatpassword)
    {
    # code...
    // encrypt password
    $password = md5($password);
    $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword); 

    if ($password==$repeatpassword)
    {
    # code...
        // Check char length of username and fullname   
    if (strlen($username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
    {
    echo "Length of username or fullname is too long!";
    }
    else
        //check password length
                        {
    if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
    {
    echo "Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
    }
    else
    {
    // register the user!
    }   
    }
    }
    else 
    echo "Your passwords do not match!";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields! ";      
    }
    }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<p>
<form action='register.php' method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    Your full name:
    </td>   
    <td>            
    <input type="text" name="fullname">
    </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Choose a username:
    </td>   
    <td>            
    <input type="text" name="username">
    </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Choose a password:
    </td>   
    <td>            
    <input type="password" name="password"> 
    </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Repeat your password:
    </td>   
    <td>            
    <input type="password" name="repeatpassword">
    </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
<p>     
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good day! I just added the html code. I'm still new to php.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not structured well. I'd suggest something like this:

```
<?php

     $submit = isset($_POST['submit']);
     if($submit)
     {
        if(empty($_POST['fullname']) || empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['repeatpassword']))
        {
           echo "Please fill in all fields!";
        }else{
           /** continue
           *   with
           *   registration
           **/

           //like strip tags in input e.t.c
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will try to use this code.

Comment: I won't use these codes $fullname, $username, $password, $repeatpassword ?

Comment: Just use them after checking if they aren't empty

Answer (score 1):

Try use `empty()`, like so:

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

if(!empty($_POST)){
  $submit = isset($_POST['submit']);

  $fullname = strip_tags(isset($_POST['fullname']));
  $username = strip_tags(isset($_POST['username']));

  $password = strip_tags(isset($_POST['password']));
  $repeatpassword = strip_tags(isset($_POST['repeatpassword']));
}

$date = date("Y-m-d");

if ($submit)
{
    if (!empty($fullname) && !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($repeatpassword))
    {


    }
    else
        echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields! ";  
}

?>

<?php
echo "<h1>Register</h1>";

if(!empty($_POST)){
  $submit = $_POST['submit'];

  $fullname = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);

  $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
  $repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']);
}

$date = date("Y-m-d");

  if ($submit)
    {
     //check for existence
  if (!empty($fullname) && !empty($username) && !empty($password) && !empty($repeatpassword))
    {
    # code...
    // encrypt password
    $password = md5($password);
    $repeatpassword = md5($repeatpassword); 

    if ($password==$repeatpassword)
    {
    # code...
        // Check char length of username and fullname   
    if (strlen($username)>25||strlen($fullname)>25)
    {
    echo "Length of username or fullname is too long!";
    }
    else
        //check password length
                        {
    if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
    {
    echo "Password must be between 6 and 25 characters";
    }
    else
    {
    // register the user!
    }   
    }
    }
    else 
      echo "Your passwords do not match!";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "Please fill in <b>all</b> fields! ";      
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: These are the errors after using empty() funtion.


Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 4 
Notice: Undefined index: fullname in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 9
Notice: Undefined index: repeatpassword in C:\wamp\www\registerloginsystem\register.php on line 10

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should check whether your form is submitted.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
//form handling code 
}
```

You can check for variables like this if you are using PHP 7 and above

```
$fullName = $_POST['fullname']?? null;
```